# Merging two columns of type factor

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to combine two columns with different length in one column with `unique` factors, here is the example:

```
list1 <- as.factor(c('1a','2r','6t'))
list2 <- as.factor(c('1a','5p','3g','2341','7','2r'))
```

to

```
NewList
  1a      
  2341       
  2r        
  3g       
  5p       
  6t
  7
```

I have tried `rbind` and `data.frame` but they seem not working very well with columns in different length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `union` in base R:

```
data.frame(newlist=union(levels(list1), levels(list2)))

#  newlist
#1      1a
#2      2r
#3      6t
#4    2341
#5      3g
#6      5p
#7       7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it works perfectly but I just have one fellow up question. `newlist` is `char` but how come the `str(data.frame(...))` is `factor`? Does `data.frame` treats values as factors?

Comment: @Y.Z. if you want `newlist` as `character`, just use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. That is, `data.frame(newlist=union(levels(list1), levels(list2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: @<989>, thanks, is there any way that I can only keep the difference between two lists. For example, turn the result to `newlist <- c('2341','3g','5p','6t','7')`

Comment: Use `setdiff` instead of `union`. You might want to accept my answer by clicking the check mark below the up/downvote icons.

Answer (score 2):

How about `as.factor(unique(c(as.character(list1), as.character(list2))))`?